# Aligning text centrally in sap.m.Button

Tags: button, sapui5

I am trying to align the text inside sap.m.Button. I used this -
"textAlign : sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Center," property, I also tried it through css by setting "align-content" property. But couldn't do it.[image]

Comment: By default the text in the **Button** will be aligned to center. You can check this in [sample.](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Button/preview)

Comment: If you don't know anything about CSS you should just NOT apply custom styles...

Comment: If you don't know anything about CSS you should TRY custom styles.. then fail then TRY again and again...

Comment: Yes, I agree with this that by default text is at center , but it got changed when I applied this border-round property and created the vertical and horizontal divider inside horizontal layout, where I created these two button. You can see the attached image also.

Comment: btw @Naveen Kumar H S, thanks for second comment, it's a great motivation for a novice in UI development. Thanks for motivating me.

Answer (score 0):

put a class in the button and write custom css for the class.

use text-align:center in css.